# How to modify the default drawing color lwjgl

Tags: java, graphics, 2d, lwjgl

Alright, so I started learning LWJGL through a few tutorials of TheCodingUniverse, but I've hit a wall at drawing lines and quads.

The code

```
package LWJGL_Learn;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;
import org.lwjgl.*;

public class SimpleOGLRenderer {

    public SimpleOGLRenderer() {
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(640, 480));
            Display.setTitle("SimpleOGLRenderer");
            //Display.setInitialBackground(256, 256, 256);
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //OpenGL Initialization
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0, 640, 480, 0, 1, -1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {

            //Render Code'
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                glVertex2i(50, 50);
                glVertex2i(80, 70);
                glVertex2i(80, 130);
                glVertex2i(50, 300);
            glEnd();

            glBegin(GL_LINES);
                glVertex2i(100, 100);
                glVertex2i(200, 200);
            glEnd();

            GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60);
        }
        Display.destroy();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SimpleOGLRenderer();
    }
}
```

Refer to around 6:50 minutes in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cQAYMkzy9rQ&list=SP19F2453814E0E315) to see what the code is supposed to be, and what its supposed to do.

Anyway, the problem is that no lines or quads show up. The screen stays black. Now, I thought maybe it was because black lines were being drawn on a black display so I modified the background color (the commented out line which went like `.setInitialDisplay...`), but with no result. The color changed, but the screen stayed white and no lines appeared. Do any of you guys know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The default color is white, but you are clearing the color buffer right before doing the Display.update()
remove:

> GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

2) You're not using the coordinates from the video, right before 6:50.